# Azure Devops pipeline can't find a checkouted template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

**My issue**

I have an Azure devops project with a template on another repository than main one's.
I try to load the template but I get this:

> /azure-pipelines.yml: File /TemplateRepository/build.yml not found in
> repository
> https://dev.azure.com/XXXXX/TestAzureDevops/_git/TemplateRepository
> branch refs/heads/main

**What I did**

**build.yml** is my template into repository: **TemplateRepository**.

**azure-pipelines.yml** is my main file.

this is my template:

```
parameters:
- name: 'name'
  default: 'name'
  type: 'string'


steps:
  - script: echo ${{parameters.name}}
```

This is my main:

```
pool:
  vmimage: 'windows-latest'

parameters:
  - name: contexts
    type: object
    default: [{
     name: macOS,
     pool: 'macOS-latest',
     sign: false
  },
  {
    name: Windows,
     pool: 'windows-latest',
     sign: true
  }]

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: Tuto-Ressources
      ref: main
      type: git
      name: TemplateRepository

stages:
  - stage: BUILD
    jobs:
      - job: test
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - checkout: Tuto-Ressources
          - script: dir 
            displayName: Dir

          - ${{ each context in parameters.contexts }}:
              - template: .\TemplateRepository\build.yml@Tuto-Ressources
                parameters:
                  name: ${{context.name}}
                  pool: ${{context.pool}}
                  sign: ${{context.sign}} 
                  buildSteps:
                    - checkout: self
                    - checkout: Tuto-Ressources
                    - bash: echo "Test module"
```

**What I tested**

If I remove the template lines from main script so I just have **script: dir** I can see my checkout on the VM and build.yml into \TemplateRepository directory.

So there is no reason it can't find my template.

I checked the branch name, it's main and I have no other one. I can see the file from the Devops Portal

**What I need**

I would like to understand what happen and what I can do.
I know there are artifact, but in this situation I don't understand whay it is not working like this because I don't change job neither stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `template` line should reference the template file by its path relative to `TemplateRepository`. If your build template resides at `\build.yml` in `TemplateRepository`, then you should just do:

```
- template: build.yml@Tuto-Ressources
```

Also, you don't need to do `- checkout: Tuto-Ressources` - the pipeline engine will know to fetch the template file from referenced repository.